# How can I sort a 2D array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I sort 2D array with JavaScript?

I want to be able to sort the first column and then after sort the second column, but without change the first sorted column.

I have:

```
arr = [[3, 2], 
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 3]]
```

I expect:

```
arr = [[1, 2], 
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 2]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just sort the first column and then when you have to swap elements you swap both column elements?

Comment: Use an ordering function that first compares the first elements. If they're equal, it compares the second elements.

Comment: Can I have a code example ?

Comment: The most intuitive way is: Transpose the array, sort the arrays of the new object using the Array sort function, and transpose it back, I cannot add the code since they marked your question as duplicated.

Comment: This is the fiddle, it prints to the console, change it to print the new array anyway you wish - https://jsfiddle.net/oL4ctufd/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const arr = [[3, 2],[1, 2],[2, 2],[2, 1],[2, 3]];
       
 arr.sort((a,b)=> (a[0] - b[0]) || a[1] - b[1]);
 
 console.log(arr);
```